# Passing in a functor to a functor

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a functor that I can pass to std::sort that will sort a vector representing the indicies for another vector of objects based on the comparison of the objects in the vector.  Rather than assume that the objects in the vector have a member operator<, I want to pass in a predicate such as I would pass into std::sort if I was sorting the vector of objects directly.

```
template <class T, class _Pr>
class SortIndexVectorObjectsHelper : public std::binary_function<ULONG, ULONG, bool>
{
    ULONG m_ulSize;
    std::vector<T> & m_aItems;
    BOOL m_bSortAscending;
    _Pr m_Comp;

public:

    SortIndexVectorObjectsHelper(std::vector<T> & aItems, _Pr Comp) : m_aItems(aItems), m_Comp(Comp), m_ulSize(0)
    {
        m_ulSize = m_aItems.size();
    }

    bool operator()( ULONG & rLeft, ULONG & rRight) 
    {
        if (rLeft < m_ulSize && rRight < m_ulSize)
        {
            T & pLeft = m_aItems[rLeft];
            T & pRight = m_aItems[rRight];

            if (pLeft && pRight)
            {
                return m_Comp(pLeft, pRight);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


};

struct SortFooByX: public std::binary_function<CFoo,CFoo, bool>
{
    BOOL m_bSortAscending;

    SortFooByX(BOOL bSortAscending)
    {
        m_bSortAscending = bSortAscending;
    }

    bool operator()( CFoo & _Left,  CFoo & _Right) 
    {

         if (m_bSortAscending)
         {
        if (_Left.X() < _Right.X())
           return true;
         }
         else
         {
        if (_Left.X() > _Right.X()) 
                   return true;

          }

          return false;
    }


};

std::sort(aFooIndicies.begin(), aFooIndicies.end(), SortIndexVectorObjectsHelper<CFoo, std::binary_function<CFoo, CFoo, bool> >(aFoo, SortFooByX(FALSE)));
```

Compiling this gives me the error that none of the 2 overloads could convert all of the argument types.

Comment: I think is because your `operator()` is supposed to receive two arguments of type `const T&` and you designed it for receiving `ULONG`.

Comment: _Pr is a reserved identifier; don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::sort(aFooIndicies.begin(), aFooIndicies.end(), SortIndexVectorObjectsHelper<CFoo, std::binary_function<CFoo, CFoo, bool> >(aFoo, SortFooByX(FALSE)));
```

The second type argument in `SortIndexVectorObjectsHelper` is wrong. The type should be `SortFooByX`, as shown below:

```
SortIndexVectorObjectsHelper<CFoo, SortFooByX> comparer(aFoo, SortFooByX(FALSE));
std::sort(aFooIndicies.begin(), aFooIndicies.end(), comparer);
```

Try this. It should work now.

Comment: I don't think so, a temporary object should work just fine (as in the OP's code). The problem is the constness. The prototype needed for the comparison function must take const references (or by value).

Comment: @Mikael: The correction is not about temporary object. It's about correct *type* of the class template. I declared `comparer` variable just for readability. Look at the second `type` of `SortIndexVectorObjectsHelper` in OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison operator needs to take const references. A const reference cannot be converted implicitly to a non-const reference, so the compiler says there is no valid overload that matches the parameter types. Just use this instead:

```
bool operator()( const ULONG & rLeft, const ULONG & rRight)
```

And I suggest you do the same in the other class that compares CFoo and CFoo. When you write a function that takes parameters by reference and does not modify the values of those parameters, you better always make the reference const, it will be clearer, safer, and less restrictive. When they are non-const, you tell the world that you want those parameters to be modifiable, when really they don't need to be, so you restrict the possible usage of the function, and in this case, this is causing the problem.

As others have mentioned too, you should be careful with your naming convention. Generally, you should avoid leading underscores _, because they are sort-of used a lot for special reserved words or keywords (double leading underscores are often used for reserved words for compiler-specific instructions and such). It is better to just avoid it, otherwise, you might eventually stumble upon very weird bugs or portability issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class Lookup, class Compare>
struct LookupCompare {
  Lookup &lookup;
  Compare cmp;

  LookupCompare(Lookup &lookup, Compare cmp=Compare()) : lookup (lookup), cmp (cmp) {}

  template<class T>
  bool operator()(T const &a, T const &b) {
    return cmp(lookup[a], lookup[b]);
  }
};
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/Youge):

```
struct Less {
  template<class T>
  bool operator()(T const &a, T const &b) {
    return std::less<T>()(a, b);
  }
};

template<class Lookup>
LookupCompare<Lookup, Less> lookup_compare(Lookup &lookup) {
  return lookup;
}
template<class Lookup, class Compare>
LookupCompare<Lookup, Compare> lookup_compare(Lookup &lookup, Compare cmp) {
  return LookupCompare<Lookup, Compare>(lookup, compare);
}

int main() {
  vector<int> lookup;
  lookup.push_back(42);
  lookup.push_back(3);
  lookup.push_back(5);

  vector<int> data;
  data.push_back(0);
  data.push_back(1);
  data.push_back(2);

  cout << data << '\n';
  sort(data.begin(), data.end(), lookup_compare(lookup));
  cout << data << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure why you're using m_ulSize, so I've left that out.  I've also simplified considerably and LookupCompare now fits on 10 SLOC.  In particular, it doesn't need an ascending flag, as you can swap std::less for std::greater or inject a "reversing" comparator.